# How to Highlight entire row of a Table using Excel VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm using a UserForm, to enter data into a worksheet.

I'd like to use a Checkbox to highlight the entire row of a table.

Example code:

```
Private Sub AddModifyAtRow(ByVal lRow As Long)
cIndex = 0
If CheckBox_NewBuild = True Then cIndex = 37
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Address")
With ws
     'This is the line I'd like to use to highlight row if Checkbox is True
    .Cells(lRow, 1).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = cIndex

     'Enter the rest of the data from the UserForm into the Table
    .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = TxBox_Building.Text
    .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = TxBox_BTS.Text
End With
```

I've also tried using this line:

```
.Range("Table5[lRow,[#ALL]]").Interior.ColorIndex = cIndex
```

Comment: please describe your problem. Does it give an error message, does not work as expected?

Comment: The first example works, using .EntireRow but the issue is it does just that.. Highlights the entire row of the worksheet.  The data is formatted in a Table, and I would like only the Table columns highlighted, not ALL the cells in the worksheet.

Comment: You can use e.g. `intersect` of entireRow and usedRange, or activesheet.listobjects(1).rows(lrow)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were *almost* there with your attempt -

```
[Table5].Rows(lrow).Interior.ColorIndex = cIndex
```

assuming your `lrow` is an integer. Just adjust the table name to your table.